# How does saving work in Fantasy Life?

Tags: fantasy-life

A few days ago I bought Fantasy Life for my girlfriend, and I tried it a couple of times, and I also like it very much. I simply love it actually, and want to have my own cartridge, so that we can play together. However, I would like to continue with my own save game. I noticed that each other save games are not shown on our own 3DS-systems (we both have our own 3DS), so I assume something is stored on your internal SD-card, but I am not sure if there is a check if you are running from the same cartridge.

Can I just continue with my save game when I buy a new Fantasy Life game (digital or cartridge)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physical cartridges store data to the cartridge; digital games store data to the SD card in the 3DS.

**CORRECTION**

I believe Fantasy Life stores save to SD card even when using a cartridge. Maybe this is due to being a large game. But I think it's encrypted to that specific cartridge so even if you buy a new one it wont show the old save.

I think you can get around it though by doing a system transfer. I have looked through it all but hopefully this helps:

[SYSTEM TRANSFER](http://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/wiki/systemtransfer)

Comment: Can a savegame be transferred between them somehow?  Maybe by connecting them to a computer?  Your answer is technically correct but doesn't actually answer the question (and my 3DS knowledge is too limited to help) of whether or not there's a way to move the savegame.

Comment: But why can't I see my girlfriends savegame when I resume my game (and vice versa)? If this is true, what is stored on the SD card that causes this behaviour?

Comment: @Mathias711 So when you're playing on your 3DS you see your save and on her 3DS you see her save?

Comment: Yep. For security, I saved in slot 2 (her game was on slot 1). So I cannot play her game on my 3ds.

Comment: @Mathias711 check updated answer

Comment: Okay, thanks. That sucks enormously. There is no option of a system transfer, because she would loose her savegame. Do you have a source of the encryption, or is it just a huh?

Comment: @Mathias711 Slightly off-topic, but I think they word you're looking for is "hunch".